# If option: show this. Else show nothing

Tags: options

First, I have to admit I'm not entirely sure on how to explain this best.

Currently I have this in my `header.php`:

```
<?php if ( is_home() OR is_front_page() ): ?>
  <meta name="description" content="<?php $options = get_option( 'schema_theme_options' ); echo $options['metadescription']; ?>">
<?php endif; ?>
```

Would it be possible to hide the remaining

```
<meta name="description" content="">
```

if no option availabe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php
$options = get_option( 'schema_theme_options' );
$meta_desc = $options['metadescription'];
?>
<?php if( ( is_home() || is_front_page() ) && '' !== $meta_desc ) : ?>
    <meta name="description" content="<?php echo $meta_desc; ?>">
<?php endif; ?>
```

It's a bit neater and a bit more foolproof than the other proposed solution.

Comment: Like a charm :) Much appreciated!

Comment: What if `$meta_desc` is `"0"`? Better use `!==` instead of `!=`.

Comment: Good catch, updated...though `0` would be a pretty crappy meta description lol

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php if ( (is_home() || is_front_page()) && ($options = get_option( 'schema_theme_options')) ): ?>
  <meta name="description" content="<?php echo $options['metadescription']; ?>">
<?php endif; ?>
```

The [get_option()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_option) function will return false if the requested option does not exist in the database (or if the options's value is false, obviously).

Comment: Hello @tbuteler, This is indeed where I get stuck, as it still leaves the empty `<meta name="description" content="">`. Could it be caused by something else in my theme options file? https://gist.github.com/1876286